# Switch to execute same function for all cases along with single print statement for one of them

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case

I have a switch case where for all cases the same function is to be executed, however for one of the cases I would also like a print statement to be printed.

I understand that to execute the same function for all cases you do something like this:

```cpp
switch(caseType)
{
    case A:
    case B:
    case C:
    case D:
        printf("Your case type = %s\n",caseType);
    break;
    default:
        printf("default\n");
    break;
}
```

In this case it would print the case type for whatever case is passed through caseType.

But what about if I want to for example have a print for case A (if the case == A, as well as the `Your case type` print?

I tried this, but it did not seem to work the way I wanted (assuming `E` is the argument passed):

```cpp
switch(caseType)
{
    case A:
    case B:
    case C:
    case D:
    case E:
    {
        printf("CASE E\n");
    }
        printf("Your case type = %s\n",caseType);
    break;
    default:
        printf("default\n");
    break;
}
```

Comment: A `switch` can only be on values of integral or enumerated types.   Printing such a type with the `%s` format gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to re-arrange your cases, so that the "special" one is on top - and then fall through:

```
switch(caseType)
{
    case E:
        printf("CASE E\n");
        // no break; here, fall through
    case A:
    case B:
    case C:
    case D:
        printf("Your case type = %s\n",caseType);
    break;
    default:
        printf("default\n");
    break;
}
```

Comment: there is [`[[fallthrough]]` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough) since C++17